# Entity Framework SaveChanges() first call is very slow

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, savechanges

I appreciate that this issue has been raised a couple of times before, but I can't find a definitive answer (maybe there isn't one!).

Anyway the title tells it all really. Create a new context, add a new entity, SaveChanges() takes 20 seconds. Add second entity in same context, SaveChanges() instant.

Any thoughts on this? :-)

============ UPDATE =============

I've created a very simple app running against my existing model to show the issue...

```
    public void Go()
    {
        ModelContainer context = new ModelContainer(DbHelper.GenerateConnectionString());

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            Order order = context.Orders.Single(c => c.Reference == "AA05056");
            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            double millisecs = (end - start).TotalMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("Query " + i + " = " + millisecs + "ms (" + millisecs / 1000 + "s)");

            start = DateTime.Now;
            order.Note = start.ToLongTimeString();
            context.SaveChanges();
            end = DateTime.Now;
            millisecs = (end - start).TotalMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("SaveChanges " + i + " = " + millisecs + "ms (" + millisecs / 1000 + "s)");

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Please do not comment on my code - unless it is an invalid test ;)

The results are:

Query 1 = 3999.2288ms (3.9992288s)
SaveChanges 1 = 3391.194ms (3.391194s)

Query 2 = 18.001ms (0.018001s)
SaveChanges 2 = 4.0002ms (0.0040002s)

Query 3 = 14.0008ms (0.0140008s)
SaveChanges 3 = 3.0002ms (0.0030002s)

Query 4 = 13.0008ms (0.0130008s)
SaveChanges 4 = 3.0002ms (0.0030002s)

Query 5 = 10.0005ms (0.0100005s)
SaveChanges 5 = 3.0002ms (0.0030002s)

The first query takes time which I assume is the view generation? Or db connection?

The first save takes nearly 4 seconds which for the more complex save in my app takes over 20 seconds which is not acceptable.

Not sure where to go with this now :-(

UPDATE...

SQL Profiler shows first query and update are fast and are not different for first. So I know delay is Entity Framework as suspected.

Comment: How big is your model? Is it first operation you are doing with your context (queries counts as well)?

Comment: @Steven - not sure what you mean there. Can you expand?

@Ladislav - This is the first SaveChanges() but there are previous queries in the same context. I am saving a relatively complex Order, where there are 10,000+ orders on the system. It's not the easiest project to debug so will probably put a sample app together to help debugging. I took out fixups (temporarily) and that fixes a number of performance issues but has had no impact on the save time. I tried pre-generating views but this seems to have little/no effect.

Comment: Although the Order is pretty complex (18 FKs etc), the second SaveChanges() on a copy of the same order is pretty much instant - if on the same context.

Comment: I meant to clarify - about 150 entities in the model.

Comment: There could be some JIT going on here as well. Are you changing the code/recompiling between test runs?

Comment: @Justin. Good thought, however I've just run tests without recompiling and see no difference.

I was thinking I should look at the SQL profiler to see how long the update was taking. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might not be the SaveChanges call - the first time you make any call to the database in EF, it has to do some initial code generation from the metadata. You can pre-generate this though at compile-time: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx

I would be surprised if that's the only problem, but it might help.

Also have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would run the following code on app start up and see how long it takes and if after that the first SaveChanges is fast.

```
    public static void UpdateDatabase()
    {
        //Note: Using SetInitializer is reconnended by Ladislav Mrnka with reputation 275k
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281423/entity-framework-4-3-run-migrations-at-application-start
        Database.SetInitializer<DAL.MyDbContext>(
            new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DAL.MyDbContext,
            Migrations.MyDbContext.Configuration>());

        using (var db = new DAL.MyDbContext()) { 
            db.Database.Initialize(false);//Execute the migrations now, not at the first access
        }
    }
```