# Entity framework 4.3 run migrations at application start

Tags: .net, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-4.3

What is the best way to execute all required db migrations at application start with EF 4.3?

Comment: Do you mean run from code? Then, here is a link you may take a look http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The best way should be using new `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer.

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(
    new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourContext, YourMigrationsConfig>());
Database.Initialize(false);
```

Comment: Where is this code intended to be placed? One can't use Database.Initialize in App_Start since it can't be used in a static context.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov: Try to add it to static constructor of your context.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: what is the purpose of `Database.Initialize(false);`? From my testing with `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`, the database is created, seeded and updated to the latest version without that second Initialize call. (in EF5...)

Comment: @demoncodemonkey: It will execute database initialization immediately. If you don't use it the initialization will happen when your application tries to access the database for the first time.

Comment: Initialize() is not a static method in EF 6.1.

Comment: @Eric J any alternative?

Comment: @user3398887: You need to have an instance of Database (e.g. from an instantiated context).

Comment: That's right. Thanks but I find out it tries to run the seed method every time when I run the application. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 6):

A great description of the EF 4.3 configuration options can be found at [EF 4.3 Configuration File Settings](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-configuration-file-settings.aspx) on the ADO.NET team blog. The very last section describes Database Initializers, including the new Code First `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer.

Although Entity Framework—like so many other features of .NET 4.x—favors convention over configuration, this is one case where it might be very useful to set the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` database initializer through your application's config file rather than explicitly code it into your application.

Comment: When using configuration, also take note of my comment on that post, to make the configuration a lot more readable.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to do it explicitly, because I use an uber-context for migration, a superset of the other migrations.  The key bit is:

```
var dbMigrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(
    new Lcmp.EF.Migrations.Migrations.Configuration());
dbMigrator.Update();
```

With a sprinkling of Elmah logging, I actually use this, called from Application_Start().  Pieces of it are stolen from others' ideas.  I'm not positive that the thread-safety Interlocked part is necessary.

```
public static int IsMigrating = 0;
private static void UpdateDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        if (0 == System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref IsMigrating, 1))
        {
            try
            {
                // Automatically migrate database to catch up.
                Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Elmah.Error(new Exception("Checking db for pending migrations.")));
                var dbMigrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(new Lcmp.EF.Migrations.Migrations.Configuration());
                var pendingMigrations = string.Join(", ", dbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations().ToArray());
                Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Elmah.Error(new Exception("The database needs these code updates: " + pendingMigrations)));
                dbMigrator.Update();
                Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Elmah.Error(new Exception("Done upgrading database.")));
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref IsMigrating, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticDataLossException ex)
    {  
        Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Elmah.Error(ex));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Elmah.Error(ex));
    }
}
```