# how to use EF 4.3 data migration feature in multi-layer application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, poco, data-access-layer, entity-framework-migrations

i have 3 projects :

ef code first in the data access layer . and service layer ,and a mvc project .

how can i use data migration when i changed ef poco class without recreating database?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set database initializer to use migrations when your application starts as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281423/entity-framework-4-3-run-migrations-at-application-start/9284447#9284447).

Comment: thanks , but why add-migration , update-database doesn't work ? i need that

Comment: Where is information about not working add-migration in your original question? And why do you ask question if you don't provide any details? Edit your question and spend some time providing details what did you done, what are you using and what doesn't work. At this point your question deserves only closing as "Not a real question".