# Create datatable reference my model with EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework-5

I use the `EntityFramework` to create datatable reference my model, but it can only create datatables one at a time. In my project, when my model is changed, how can I do to have the datatable also changed ?

Do I need to modify my database? Is there a method to create or modify automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The method is called EF migrations - check these tutorials ([Automatic migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj554735), [Code migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621)). If you don't use migrations your database will not be updated - the only option offered by EF without migrations is to delete database and let it create a new one from scratch.

Comment: your mean that i create a class to do it, in my website it can't update then  my website is starting.?

Comment: your mean that i create a class to do it, in my website it can't update then  my website is starting.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281423/entity-framework-4-3-run-migrations-at-application-start/9284447#9284447