# How to trigger migration with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6

I want to trigger database migration through code to latest version.

I have already configured the migrations and they work fine but the only way I can get them to migrate is by querying the database which I think shouldn't be needed.

I am sure I have just missed something in the documentation to trigger the migration but if someone can point me in the right direction it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a related article that answered this all I need to do is call `Database.Initialize(false);` in my routine to upgrade the database.

[Entity framework 4.3 run migrations at application start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281423/entity-framework-4-3-run-migrations-at-application-start)