# Run Migrations command if not have visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, command, migration

I'm publishing a website ASP.NET MVC and get this error:

“Migrations is enabled for context ‘Context’ but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the ‘Update-Database’ command from the Package Manager Console.”

I can't install visual studio on server so i can't run ‘Update-Database’ command.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Take a look at this questions: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848746/using-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-in-production
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281423/entity-framework-4-3-run-migrations-at-application-start

Answer (score 1):

1. Find migrate.exe (YourApp\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools) and paste it in bin folder on the server.
2. Open Command Prompt on the server.
3. Run below commands

   cd "C:\Websites\YourApp\bin" migrate.exe YourAppName.Api.dll /startupconfigurationfile:..\Web.config /verbose

Please Note that *YourAppName.Api.dll* should be the DLL having *Enabled Migration*.

Comment: I have this problem: 
ERROR: Could not load assembly 'Update-Database'. (If you are using Code First Migrations inside Visual Studio this can happen if the startUp project for your solution does not reference the project that contains your migrations. You can either change the startUp project for your solution or use the -StartUpProjectName parameter.)

Answer (score -1):

you do not need to install visual studio on the server.

if you have your database connection string setup in web.config you should be able to run update-database in the package manager console and it will update your database on your web host.

Comment: @Matta Tabor: Can you explain in more detail ?